# Slow Writing to File in Lua

Tags: file, file-io, io, lua, file-writing

I am trying to write some data to a text file in Lua, but for some reason it is very slow (8s for just 100 lines). More than 100 lines slows down further and over 1000 lines, my GPU runs out of memory. Where am I going wrong, please? Do I need to add `collectgarbage()` somewhere? Thanks.

```
fp = io.open(('predictions/valid_test.txt'), "w")
local soft = nn.SoftMax()
local n = 100

for i = 1, n do
   local t_data = data[{{start_idx, end_idx},{},{},{}}]
   local outputs = model:forward(t_data):float()
   local soft_data = soft:forward(outputs)
   fp:write(fname[i] .. ',' ..  soft_data[1] .. ',' .. '\n')
   xlua.progress(i, n)
end
fp.close()
```

Comment: Just comment `fp:write(` line and run to see either it file write is slow.

Comment: Lua can write to files very quickly. I believe the problem you are experiencing making it slow is the other lines in the loop. Have you tested their speed?

Answer (score 1):

The error was actually a memory leak in Torch. Not sure why this was downvoted though, I wasn't implying that Lua is deficient! ;o